# Share MongoModule in different services

Tags: typescript, mongodb, nestjs

I try to get user data from my mongodb in a different nestjs service.

My userModule is marked as `@Global`

```js
@Global()
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([ { name: 'User', schema: UserSchema } ]),
    PassportModule,
    JwtModule.registerAsync({
      useFactory: () => ({
        secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
        signOptions: { expiresIn: '15m' },
      }),
    }),
  ],
  providers: [ UserResolver, UserService, JwtStrategy ],
  exports: [ UserService ],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([
      { name: 'Example', schema: ExampleSchema },
    ]),
  ],
  providers: [ ExampleService, ExampleResolver ],
})
export class ExampleModule {}
```

I try to load the user by my id from the context. I inject the User model into constructor

For Example, I have a settings service

```js
import { Model } from 'mongoose'
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common'
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose'
...
@Injectable()
export class ExampleService {
  constructor (
    @InjectModel('Example') private readonly ExampleModel: Model<ExampleDocument>,
    @InjectModel('User') private readonly UserModel: Model<UserDocument>,
  ) {}

  async create ({ ctx, data }: { ctx: Ctx, data: ExampleCreateInput }): Promise<Example> {
    const user = await this.userModel.findById(ctx.user._id)
```

I get the following error in my console, but it should be already imported because of the `@Global`. When I try to import manually, the issue is still there.

```sh
app_1            | Potential solutions:
app_1            | - If UserModel is a provider, is it part of the current PortfolioModule?
app_1            | - If UserModel is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within PortfolioModule?
app_1            |   @Module({
app_1            |     imports: [ /* the Module containing UserModel */ ]
app_1            |   })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue were pretty simple to add the UserModule in my service I also need to add it in my mongoose import in my ExampleModule.

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([
      { name: 'Example', schema: ExampleSchema },
      { name: 'User', schema: UserSchema },
    ]),
  ],
  providers: [ ExampleService, ExampleResolver ],
})
export class ExampleModule {}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of adding the `user` schema to the `MongooseModule` in the `ExampleModule`, you could instead add the `MongooseModule` to the `exports of the` UserModule` and take advantage of [module re-exporting](https://docs.nestjs.com/modules#module-re-exporting).

**It is of my opinion**, however, that you should instead export the `UserService` from the `UserModule` and not create another connection point to the user document in mongoose, staying closer to domain driven design. You have a service that talks to the table for you. You use that service in other services to get access without exposing the table directly, it's like why we write API endpoints instead of letting people read and write directly from the database: control and conformity. Using a service allows you to keep all the code for the `UserSchema` consolidated, and validated in the same way. But again, that's all my opinion.

Comment: Marvelously explained the architecture. I was having this exact questioning: "should I reuse my DB model across services or use the service itself across services?". From the performance point of view, I was wondering if sharing the model would be more efficient, as the flow would not have to go through another service, but I guess that is just insignificant, right?